# Constant kernel crashes with pd.concat() and df.append()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am writing a data processing frontend and I want to implement a feature to combine datasets, but when testing my code in Jupyter Notebooks, I get kernel crashes even for small dataframes.

The weird thing is that I only get these crashes when the concat() is called within a larger function - when performing the operation in isolation in Jupyter Notebooks, it works just fine.

I got around this problem by doing

```
df.iloc[len(df.index):,:] = df_2
```

In place of

```
df = pd.concat([df,df_2], sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

but this is a lot less efficient.

I have no idea how to debug this issue. Memory and CPU usage are not high, I get no exceptions, just the kernel crashes.